# How to add footer to ReorderableListView in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

Trying to make a ui that contains Header and Footer with **rearrangeable content** items. There is a property called **header** from which we can add header item. But what to do if I want to add **footer** item as well.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyStickyHeader extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _MyStickyHeaderState();
  }
}

class _MyStickyHeaderState extends State<MyStickyHeader> {
  List<Widget> _list = [
    Text("Apple"),
    Text("Ball"),
    Text("Cat"),
    Text("Dog"),
    Text("Elephant")
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, left: 10),
      color: Colors.white,
      child: showData(),
    );
  }

  Widget showData() {
    return Container(
      child: ReorderableListView(
        header: Container(
          height: 100,
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
        children: _list
            .map((item) => Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  key: Key("${(item as Text).data}"),
                  child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
                      Expanded(
                        child: item,
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ))
            .toList(),
        onReorder: (int start, int current) {
          // dragging from top to bottom
          if (start < current) {
            int end = current - 1;
            Widget startItem = _list[start];
            int i = 0;
            int local = start;
            do {
              _list[local] = _list[++local];
              i++;
            } while (i < end - start);
            _list[end] = startItem;
          }

          // dragging from bottom to top
          if (start > current) {
            Widget startItem = _list[start];
            for (int i = start; i > current; i--) {
              _list[i] = _list[i - 1];
            }
            _list[current] = startItem;
          }
          setState(() {});
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Last element of your list can be a footer. It has to be a widget with onLongPress property. For example:

```
ReorderableListView(
      onReorder: (int oldIndex, int newIndex) {},
      children: List.generate(someList.items.length + 1, (index) {
        if (index < someList.items.length)
          return ListTile(
            key: Key(someList.items[index].description),
          );
        else
          return RaisedButton(key: Key('footer'), onPressed: () {}, onLongPress: (){}, child: Text('Button'));
      })),
```

Comment: I had the same issue and this kind of solved it. But the problem is that even though you can't roeder this specific item others in the list can take its place

Answer (score 1):

If you wrap your `ReorderableListView` with a `Column` and an `Expanded` widget, you can add a `Container` at the bottom to act as a footer:

```
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Expanded(
      child: ReorderableListView(
        header: Container(
          height: 100,
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
        children: _list
          .map((item) => Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          key: Key("${(item as Text).data}"),
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
              Expanded(
                child: item,
              )
            ],
          ),
        )).toList(),
        onReorder: (int start, int current) {
          // dragging from top to bottom
          if (start < current) {
            int end = current - 1;
            Widget startItem = _list[start];
            int i = 0;
            int local = start;
            do {
              _list[local] = _list[++local];
              i++;
            } while (i < end - start);
            _list[end] = startItem;
          }

          // dragging from bottom to top
          if (start > current) {
            Widget startItem = _list[start];
            for (int i = start; i > current; i--) {
              _list[i] = _list[i - 1];
            }
            _list[current] = startItem;
          }
          setState(() {});
        },
      ),
    ),
    Container(
      height: 40,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Text('Footer'),
      color: Colors.orange,
    ),
  ],
),
```

Comment: I run into the same problem. Your solution creates a fixed footer below the ReorderableListView but the question was to have a footer at the end of the list view which may scroll out of viewport but cannot change its position within the list. I have opened a feature request to add a footer to ReorderableListView. (Requires only three more lines ;-)

Comment: @Jemolah I'm struggling with exactly this. Did you ever solve it? Care to share those three lines of code :-)

Answer (score 1):

To implement such view i recommend using **Slivers**.

**benefits**:

1. Sticky header/Footer.
2. infinity body/content scroll.

check the **code** below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
          SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
              [
                Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  height: 50,
                  color: Colors.orangeAccent,
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      'Header',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, letterSpacing:4),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: 100,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return ListTile(
                      title: Center(child: Text('$index')),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SliverFillRemaining(
            hasScrollBody: false,
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                height: 50,
                color: Colors.blueAccent,
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    'Footer',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, letterSpacing: 4),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

For more detail take a look here:

https://itnext.io/create-a-header-footer-with-scrollable-body-view-in-flutter-5551087270de